# How to change/cropping portrait to be landscape image in the table?

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie at web programming, so for setting width there's no problem, but when uploading a portrait image it looks annoying & I want all the images to be landscape. This is what I want: https://d8e7ec01-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/vanyfiles/1-horz.jpg

css:

```
#thumb_news{
    padding:5px;
}
#thumb_img{
    width:25%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

and html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="thumb_img"><img src="images/e-magz.png" width="100%" /></td>
    <td id="thumb_news">
      <div id="date">February 7,2013</div>
      <a href="#">This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your thumb_img element a fixed height, and `overflow:hidden`, like so:

```
#thumb_img{
width:25%;
height:120px;
overflow:hidden;
left:0;
right:0;
padding-top:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: thank you, 
but it makes the image oppressed. https://d8e7ec01-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/vanyfiles/penyet.jpg

do u have another idea to avoid oppressed image ?

Answer (score 0):

Create wrapper for img element. Set CSS form wrapper:

```
.img_wrapper {
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   ...
}
```

this will cut the rest of the image for sure and it will not oppressed image.

If you want also to center the image verticaly set negative top margin for example if image wrapper is 100px and image has 200px than set:

```
.img_wrapper img {
   margin-top: -50px; // (200 - 100) / 2
   ...
   // or you can use
   position: relative;
   top: -50px;
   ...
}
```

but you must use JS for this to calculate negative top margin.
I'm wondering if there is some solution for this without JS.